# Error in POSIXlt

Tags: r

Date in my data is in YYYY-dd-mm format.`2015-01-07,2015-01-08` are some sample dates.I want to extract week number from this date. I used following code

```
week_number <- as.POSIXlt(data_tmp2$my_date)
data_tmp2$week_number=strftime(data_tmp2,format="%W")
```

After running the second line,I'm getting following error

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz) : 
do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: try with `strftime(week_number,format="%W")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
week(as.Date("2015-01-07", format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can convert to `Date` class with `as.Date` and use `format` to extract the week

```
format(as.Date("2015-01-07", format = "%Y-%d-%m"), "%W")
#[1] "26"
```

---

The code in the OP's post should work well if it was applied to the concerned column instead of a `data.frame`

```
strftime(as.POSIXlt("2015-01-07", format = "%Y-%d-%m"), "%W")
#[1] "26"
```

i.e.

```
strftime(as.POSIXlt(data_tmp2$my_date, format = "%Y-%d-%m"), format="%W")
```

NOTE: It is not clear whether the `format` is `"%Y-%d-%m"` or the usual `Date` class format i.e. `%Y-%m-%d` as it could be a typo in the OP's post.

Comment: You need to specify a format to parse OP's dares correctly.